FFMPEG on Buildroot
I am new to linux and trying to install Ffmpeg on buildroot which I've installed in raspberrypi 3. My main goal is to display uvc camera on display But whenever I'm trying to execute ffplay  /dev/videoO. It shows error " could not initialize SDL - No available video device did you set the DISPLAY variable ? " I installed SDl1.2 and sdl2. I've set raspberrypi3_ defconfig. It would be very helpful for me if I get it done. Thank you

"did you set the DISPLAY variable ?" - Answer the question: Did you set the Linux (not Buildroot) environment variable named DISPLAY ???  Study https://web.archive.org/web/20170713001430/http://sc.tamu.edu/help/general/unix/vars.html

No I haven't. In fact I don't know how to do so.
